# Fitnesse: Using Different set of Test data for running same tests on Diff Enviornmnents

Tags: variables, fitnesse

We have `Fitnesse` symbols defined like below:

```
!define acc {12121212}
```

We need to run the tests on various environments like `Dev`, `SIT`, `UAT`.
The `acc` here may change for each `Env`.

I want to specify three symbols on the page:

```
!define devacc {12121212}
!define sitacc {12121223}
!define uatacc {12121224}
```

and use `if` statement somehow to manage the symbol as per the `Env` specified.
We have global symbol defined on as:

```
!define env {dev}
```

So whenever this symbol value is changed to sit, I want my tests to pick up the symbol `sitacc`. Is there any way in `Fitnesse` to manage this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve what you describe with symbols in the wiki.

What I do to run tests against multiple environments is to have branches (in version control) of my wiki for different environments. In the wiki I have symbols that represent correct values for a single environment. The main difference of the wiki content between the branches are the values specified for the symbols.
The tests are run (independently) from each branch to the corresponding environment.

So in your case the 'dev branch' would contain `!define acc {12121212}` and the 'sit branch' would have the same page but with `!define acc {12121223}`.

Having the branches also allows me to maintain correct tests sets for each environment: new features are tested in the 'dev branch' first, and those tests are merged to the 'test branch' when the code to be tested is deployed to the test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "!include" option: you can add any page.

Also you can change the "content.txt" files before testing start (our CI do it) and replace all variables to different. These file contains the test data which is presented in the Edit dialog.

Basically FitNesse does not support if-else branches, while and all other "programming" patterns, because it is developed for simple acceptance testing, the tool which helps Business Analytics.